# Linux Kernel Module - Creating proc file - proc_root undeclared error

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I copy and paste code from this URL for creating and reading/writing a proc file using a kernel module and get the error that proc_root is undeclared. This same example is on a few sites so I assume it works. Any ideas why I'd get this error? Does my makefile need something different. Below is my makefile as well:

Example code for a basic proc file creation (direct copy and paste to get initial test done):
http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html#AEN769

**Makefile** I'm using:

```
obj-m    := counter.o

KDIR    := /MY/LINUX/SRC

PWD    := $(shell pwd)

default:
 $(MAKE) ARCH=um -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That example is out of date.  Under the current kernel API, pass `NULL` for the root of procfs.

Also, instead of `create_proc_entry`, you should use `proc_create()` with a proper `const struct file_operations *`.

Comment: Great! Thanks. Now I can get it to compile properly.

Answer (score 9):

There has been a change in the interface to create an entry in the proc file system. You can have a look at http://pointer-overloading.blogspot.in/2013/09/linux-creating-entry-in-proc-file.html for details

Here is a 'hello_proc' example with the new interface:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/seq_file.h>

static int hello_proc_show(struct seq_file *m, void *v) {
  seq_printf(m, "Hello proc!\n");
  return 0;
}

static int hello_proc_open(struct inode *inode, struct  file *file) {
  return single_open(file, hello_proc_show, NULL);
}

static const struct file_operations hello_proc_fops = {
  .owner = THIS_MODULE,
  .open = hello_proc_open,
  .read = seq_read,
  .llseek = seq_lseek,
  .release = single_release,
};

static int __init hello_proc_init(void) {
  proc_create("hello_proc", 0, NULL, &hello_proc_fops);
  return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_proc_exit(void) {
  remove_proc_entry("hello_proc", NULL);
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
module_init(hello_proc_init);
module_exit(hello_proc_exit);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:

[The above accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2531807/8458616) might have worked for you. It no longer works in GNU/Linux 5.6.y and above! Since 5.6, `proc_create()` will accept `proc_ops` as argument instead of `file_operations`. Fields are prepended with `proc_` and there's no `owner` field in `proc_ops` ([check here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/proc_fs.h#n29)).

As a side note, a programmer would wish for a portable code. In this, same code shall work across different versions of GNU/Linux. So, you may also need to use `LINUX_VERSION_CODE`, `KERNEL_VERSION(5,6,0)` macros which are in `linux/version.h`. For example,

```
#include <linux/version.h>

...
...

#if (LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(5,6,0))
static struct file_operations
#elif (LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(5,6,0))
static struct proc_ops
#endif
proc_file_ops = {
#if (LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(5,6,0))
 owner : THIS_MODULE,
 read : proc_file_read,
 write : proc_file_write
#elif (LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(5,6,0))
 proc_read : proc_file_read,
 proc_write : proc_file_write
#endif
};

...
...
```

AFAIK apart from these, I couldn't note any other major changes :)