# error in loadable kernel module as make: nothing to be done for all?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, makefile, procfs

The functions you write to provide procfs interfaces is just code that is part of your LKM source.

http://linux.die.net/lkmpg/x769.html has a simple example using procfs, reproduced here:

I copied the code from above link -
You'll find a tutorial for building kernel modules at http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-module.html. The summary of that is:

1) Ensure you have kernel source installed in /usr/src.

2) Create a makefile that looks like:

```
obj-m = procfs2.o
KVERSION = $(shell uname -r)
all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

3) build the module with the command make 4) load the module into memory with the command insmod procfs2.ko (do this as the root user)

I copied the code and created the MAKEFILE and later if I give the make command from the console then it is showing as : make: nothing to be done for all. could someone please tell me what could be the error ??

Comment: Maybe it's already built.  Try cleaning first.

Comment: if i give make clean then it is showing make : nothing to be done for clean.

Comment: What does `ls -l "/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build"` show?

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Apr 13 23:49 /lib/modules/3.2.48-rt69-2/build -> /usr/src/linux-source-3.2.48-rt69-2

Comment: @user3458454 can first ensure that before `make` command you give  TAB? because replacing,them by spaces will cause `Makefile` to malfunction.

Comment: after make ?? or after all: ??

Comment: @user3458454 look my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of a Makefile for a kernel module.

the important thing here to note is that the dots shown below must be replaced by a **TAB**, replacing them by **spaces** will cause Makefile to malfunction.

```
obj-m += hello.o

all:
.......make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
.......make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: could you please answer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101224/how-to-send-the-kernel-data-to-the-user-the-space-using-procfs

Comment: please can I have your email id ?? I need some suggestions.

Comment: I am getting some errors when I run the make command : error: proc_root undeclared
error: struct proc_dir_entry has no member named 'owner'

Comment: @user3458454 look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531730/linux-kernel-module-creating-proc-file-proc-root-undeclared-error

Comment: to perform a procfile_read function from kernel to user then I should create a file operations structure used to define file manipulation callbacks for our pseudo-file. but If i give .read = procfile_read, (I am giving within the structure then showing error as procfile_read is undeclared here)

Comment: if I use this link : http://pointer-overloading.blogspot.in/2013/09/linux-creating-entry-in-proc-file.html   if I want to perform procfile_read function as shown in the code above then how to specify it in the file operation structure ?